# hg incoming display the repository root path

Tags: mercurial

Executing the Mercurial command:
hg in -q

produces a list like below.
123:b64543
124:ef312a

This command will be execute on multiple repo's. How can we append the repository path to the above output to identify the repo? Executing command 'hg root' gives us that information but we only want to know about the path if the repo has new changeset. We looked at template but could not find a variable that gave us the right information.

Apppreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for *appending* the root path to `hg incoming` is to concatenate the two commands with `&&` (assuming you're using Unix):

```
hg in -q && hg root
```

This works because `hg incoming` will return 0 if there are incoming changes, 1 otherwise (or a non-zero value if there was an error).

For more sophisticated manipulation of the output, sed can usually do it. For example, the following command *prepends* the root to the output:

```
hg in -q | sed -e "1i$(hg root)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd resort to a bit bash and call `hg root` within the template. Assuming all directories are sub-directories of the current one (otherwise give the list of dirs differently):

```
for i in *; do [ -d $i/.hg ] && hg incoming -R$i --template "$(hg root -R$i) {rev}:{node|short}\n"; done
```